# remove long hashtags trail from string

Tags: regex, string

I want regular expression which will remove hashtags at the end of a string. For example:

> *WCW * $14 black vans (size 6)* $8 black fishnet Jacket (size large)* $6 giraffe tank top (size small)* $8 denim shorts (size 2)* $6 red see through purse #platosclosetmooresville #platosclosetlakenorman #resale #gentlyused #preloved #lakenorman #mooresville #MVL #LKN #fashionista #recycleyourstyle #cornelius #davidson #concord #kannapolis #statesville #salisbury #bargainista #lknshopping #mooresvilleshopping #GetCash #SellYourItems #shopping #BargainShopper #ShopLocal #PlatosCloset #giraffe #OOTD #WCW

I have written a regular expression to match the hashtag trail. `/#[#\w\s]*\z/`. also tried with `/#[#\w\s]*$/u`. But they only return

> #lknshopping #mooresvilleshopping #GetCash #SellYourItems #shopping #BargainShopper #ShopLocal #PlatosCloset #giraffe #OOTD #WCW

It should capture all of:

> #platosclosetmooresville #platosclosetlakenorman #resale #gentlyused #preloved #lakenorman #mooresville #MVL #LKN #fashionista #recycleyourstyle #cornelius #davidson #concord #kannapolis #statesville #salisbury #bargainista #lknshopping #mooresvilleshopping #GetCash #SellYourItems #shopping #BargainShopper #ShopLocal #PlatosCloset #giraffe #OOTD #WCW

The solution should not match hashtags in the middle of the string.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showcase your efforts to the community for getting help.

Comment: What do those `*` mean in your sentences? How you define a sentence if it has not dot in the end?

Comment: This simple RegEx should do it: /#.+$/ It finds a '#' and then the rest of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `#[#\w\s]*\z` starts at matching a `#` and is followed by a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match one out of several characters. That character class is repeated zero or more times so it would for example also match `###a bc` or just the single starting `#`

If you want to match hashtags that are as a trail of a sentence and there can not be a word that is not a hashtag in between you could use:

`#\w+(?:\s+#\w+)*\z`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y32S9v/1)

**Explanation**

- `#` Match literally
- `\w+` Match one or more times a word character
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\s+#\w+` match one or more times a whitespace character followed by `#` and match one or more times a word character
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
- `\z` Assert end of the string

Comment: Thanks for solution and explanation. That's really helpful.

Comment: I have one more scenario `Bring your Plato’s Closet recyclable tote bag #TODAY and #SAVE 15% off all regular-priced inventory!__________#totebagarmy #vipshopping #totebagtuesday #platosclosetmooresville #platosclosetlakenorman #resale #gentlyused #preloved #lakenorman #mooresville #domo #MVL #LKN #designerforless #recycleyourstyle #davidson #davidsoncollege #statesville #salisbury #upscaleresale #shoplkn #shopmooresville #lknshopping #mooresvilleshopping :camera@platosclosetmooresville` here hashtags tail should match from #totebagarmy to #mooresvilleshopping

Comment: /#\w+\s(#\w+\s)+(#\w+)*/g . This regx is working for my current and previous scenario.

Comment: But that would not match for example: https://regex101.com/r/T3N4JG/1
You could use a negative lookahead to assert that there are not more hash tags following. Try [`#\w+(?:\s+#\w+)*(?!.*#\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/4AUVx7/1)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you want to each hashtag string:

- (without #): `(?<=#)[[:alpha:]]*` check [this](https://regex101.com/r/yWxCTX/3/)
- (with #): `#[a-zA-Z]+` check [this](https://regex101.com/r/yWxCTX/4/)